# Deny user access to edit post while allow him to edit custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

I have created a custom post type called '*Tender*' using **pods framework**. Then I created a custom role using the '*roles and capabilities*' component of pods framework. I gave that role following capabilities:

> 1. delete_private_tenders
> 2. delete_published_tenders
> 3. delete_tender
> 4. delete_tenders
> 5. edit_private_tenders
> 6. edit_published_tenders
> 7. edit_tender
> 8. edit_tenders
> 9. publish_tenders
> 10. read_private_tenders
> 11. read_tender
> 12. read

Afterwards created a user and gave him the above role, but upon signing in, I was not able to see the dashboard. After some trial and error, I found out that if the role does not have ***edit_post*** capability, user cannot access dashboard. I **do not want the user** to be able to **edit a post**. Is there is any solution exists for the dilemma ?

Comment: if you are using woocommerce, that's the root of your problem. There is a tweak to remove WooCommerce filter.